# How to write correct HTML generator in Kotlin

Tags: lambda, functional-programming, kotlin

I'm learning Kotlin and reading the section [Type-Safe Builders](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/type-safe-builders.html)

I followed it's example and coded some tests and then I found a problem which I couldn't understand.
The problem is that it seem that the following code is equivalent:

1. Nested `head`

   ```
   html {
       head {
           title { +"First Title" }
           head {
               title { +"Second Title" }
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Two `head` on the same level

   ```
   html {
       head {
           title { +"Second Title" }
       }

       head {
           title { +"First Title" }
       }
   }
   ```

These two function call return same result.
[Test result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dyGE.png)

**I think the correct result should be "What You See Is What You Get".**

Comment: What happens if you print test1 and test2 separately?

Comment: @DougStevenson Same result.

Comment: [You can try online](http://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/nei3a1vd39bscpdg48t9oicpbu/3u9nntolr1tdgg9pabf2nlls4d)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look carefully at the "full definition of the com.example.html package", you'll see that `head` is a method of `HTML`.  This means that `head` can only be called on an instance of `HTML`.  The way you're expecting it to work, there would have to be a `head` member of the `Head` class.

In your first example code, the second invocation of `head` is actually being called on the outer `html` instance receiver.  This means you're effective adding the new element it creates to `html` and *not* its immediately enclosing `head`.

To put this another way, your first code example is equivalent to this:

```
html {
    head {
        title { +"First Title" }
        this@html.head {
            title { +"Second Title" }
        }
    }
}
```

Note `this@html` which is qualifying exactly which outer receiver instance is being used to invoke `head`. Also note that `this@head` won't compile because, as I said, the `Head` class does not have a `head` method.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As you said, head should only be called on an instance of HTML. In my first example, it should either be a semantics error which can't pass compile or just effect nothing which will add a Head into HTML.

Comment: No, the second head still gets created and added to the `children` list of the outer html. Either, way you end up with the same set of children. The whole thing doesn't get converted to a string until the very end.  Try walking through in a debugger to see for yourself what happens at runtime.

Comment: I wonder how Kotlin makes the second invocation of `head` be called on the outer `html` instance. Does the compiler just try to find a `head` function in `Head` and then in `HTML` and finally transform the invocation of `head` to `this@html.head`?

Comment: Yes, the compiler is smart.  It figures it out a way to make it work. I don't know for a fact, but it appears that the compiler checks each scope for a receiver that's able to handle the `head` method invocation, and picks the first one it finds, starting from the inside.

Comment: Thanks for your patience. I'll use debugger to help me understand what just happens. It's just a little more difficult than to debug a program in Java 7.